# Regex not working as should in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I trying to replace some line breaks from a file in C#, given a specific pattern:

`(?m)(^\t[0-9A-Z#].+$)\r?\n`

File example structure

```
    1   1   1   1
ab  as  as  
    123 1   2
        13
    32  3   12  2
ds  ds  12
```

Applying `$1\t` as replace, I expect to get the following result:

```
    1   1   1   1   ab  as  as  
    123 1   2           13
    32  3   12  2   ds  ds  12
```

In fact, this replace is working properly at [regexr](http://regexr.com/396mp).

But in C# the file simply return no matches. Is any particularity in this regex that .net matches differentially?

```
public void masterDataEleb()
{
    // Tried both with (?m) and RegexOptions.Multiline, not working
    Regex masterDataRegex = new Regex(@"(^\t[0-9A-Z#].+$)\r?\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    string replaceTo = "$1\t";

    string textFile = File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.Default);
    textFile = masterDataRegex.Replace(textFile, replaceTo);

    File.WriteAllText(filePath, textFile, Encoding.Default);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to enter `"$1\t"` for `replaceTo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your expression (ignoring your capture group), you have the sequence:

`$\r?\n`

When you use [RegexOptions.Multiline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx#End) in .NET, the `$` anchor greedily matches `LF`.  Your match fails because there is no sequence `LFCRLF` or `LFLF` in your file.

You should instead try using the pattern `\r?$` to match the end of your line.

The reason your pattern does work at regexr may be a difference in behavior of the `$` anchor (for example, the behavior at regexr appears to match `$` before the LF, although I suspect it may fail with input lines ending in CRLF for similar reasons).

Comment: The problem is really `$`. I changed it to `\r?\n` and made `.+` non-greedy and I get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. substitute with `$1\t$2$3`

```
([^\r\n]*)\r?\n([^\r\n]*)(\r?\n?)
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/rZ0iD6/2)

Pattern explanation:

```
([^\r\n]*)    Group everything till new line is found
\r?\n         New line is found
([^\r\n]*)    Group everything till new line is found
(\r?\n?)      New line is found(optional)
```